# Spectron Headless Testing on CentOS 7 not working

Tags: node.js, linux, testing, electron

**Environment**

- Mac OSX 10.11.5 *running* Vagrant 1.8.4 *running* Cent OS 7
- Node v6.4.0
- Npm v3.10.3
- Electron-prebuilt ^1.2.0
- Electron-packager ^7.6.0
- Spectron v3.3.0

Running test headless, with `Xvfb`

- `Xvfb :99 -screen 0 1024x768x24 +extension RANDR &`
- `export DISPLAY=':99.0'`

**Setup**

- I've `git cloned` the [electron-quick-start](https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start) repo.
- Then built it via `electron-packager . MyApp --platform=linux --arch=x64 --prune` (Script in package.json)
- Then run test: `node test_app.js`

**Output**

`Running app
Main window is visible: true
Check text
Test failed An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.
Stopping the application`

**Additional Notes**

Everything seems to be working, since Main window visibility test returns true, but Spectron doesn't seem able to query elements of the HTML as I expected.

Why do I get: `An element could not be located on the page using the given search`?

Also, title is empty. Found out by removing `getText` test, and assert for title fails, saying " " does not equal `"Hello World!"`

I've also confirmed the app runs by building for Mac OS and checking it, but what I want to do is run headless tests for my CI setup.

**Snippets**

index.html / test_app.js

```js
//A simple test to verify a visible window is opened with a title
var Application = require('spectron').Application
var assert = require('assert')

var app = new Application({
  path: '/home/vagrant/electron-quick-start/MyApp-linux-x64/MyApp'})

console.log('Running app')

app.start()
    .then(function () {
    return app.browserWindow.isVisible()
    })
    .then(function (isVisible) {
    console.log('Main window is visible: ' + isVisible)
    })
    .then(function () {
    console.log('Check text')
    return app.client.getText('#par')    
    })
    .then(function (text) {
    assert.equal(text, "Does this work?")
    })
    .then(function () {
    console.log('Check the windows title')
    return app.client.getTitle()
    })
    .then(function (title) {
    assert.equal(title, 'Hello World!')
    })
    .then(function () {
    console.log('Stopping the application')
    return app.stop()
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
    //Log any failures
    console.error('Test failed', error.message)
    console.log('Stopping the application')
    return app.stop()
    })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello World!</title>
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <p id="par">Does this work?</p>
  </body>
  
  <script>
    require('./renderer.js')
  </script>
</html>
```

**xwd screenshot**

- Ran the app: `npm start`

**Output**

`>electron-quick-start@1.0.0 start /home/vagrant/electron-quick-start`

`>electron .`

`Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":99.0".`

`Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":99.0".`

**Generated screenshot**

- `xwd -root -silent > grab.xwd`
- `convert grab.xwd grab.jpg`

[image]

Comment: Tried `Xvfb :99 -screen 0 1024x768x24 +extension RANDR &` to get rid of `Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":99.0".` when I run the test. It got rid of the messages, but same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed my test_app.js to use arrow functions, perhaps I fixed some subtle bug in the process, but now it works!

**Output**

`Running app...`

`Main window is visible:  true`

`Checking text...`

`Text:  Does this work?`

`Checking the windows title...`

`Title:  Hello World!`

`Stopping the application`

**New test_app.js**

```js
//A simple test to verify a visible window is opened with a title
var Application = require('spectron').Application
var assert = require('assert')

var app = new Application({
  path: '/home/vagrant/electron-quick-start/MyApp-linux-x64/MyApp'})

console.log('Running app...')

app.start()
    .then(() => app.browserWindow.isVisible())
    .then((isVisible) => console.log('Main window is visible: ', isVisible))
    .then(() => {
        console.log('Checking text...')
        return app.client.getText('#par')    
    })
    .then((text) => {
        assert.equal(text, "Does this work?")
        console.log("Text: ", text)   
    })
    .then(() => {
        console.log('Checking the windows title...')
        return app.client.getTitle()
    })
    .then((title) => {
        assert.equal(title, 'Hello World!')
        console.log("Title: ", title)
    })
    .then(() => {
        console.log('Stopping the application')
        return app.stop()
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        //Log any failures
        console.error('Test failed: ', error.message)
        console.log('Stopping the application')
        return app.stop()
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was the server had an invalid SSL certificate and chrome does not automatically accept it in headless mode (it does in non-headless).

More info here: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/headless-dev/eiudRsYdc3A